# How to make undefined host go to default Page in apache2 virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I am using named Virtual hosts

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ramesh@thegeekstuff.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/thegeekstuff"
    ServerName test1.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.test1.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/thegeekstuff/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/thegeekstuff/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ramesh@top5freeware.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/top5freeware"
    ServerName test2.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.test2.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/top5freeware/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/top5freeware/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

At the moment i have not defined `www.mydomain.com` but when i open in browser it goes to my `test1.mydomain.com`

Is there any way that if i did not explicitly define that it redirect to either APache conf page

Also if i type ip address only then it also goes to that site.

I want that also to go to that undefiend page or something else

Answer (score 3):

The site that gets served when no `<VirtualHost>` matches for that `NameVirtualHost` is the first one to load.

Just put a `<VirtualHost>` block above your others with a bogus `ServerName`, which serves the content that you want to be default.

Comment: so u mean first i need to have default index.html at location like `/var/www/default/index.html` then in serverbname i use `www.blabla.com` then evrything will go there

Comment: @user1513613 Right, you will create a separate `<VirtualHost>` block that will be used as the default for catching requests to domains that aren't covered by a different one.